# How to get string values from two dimensional array and assign to a one dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, iteration

Assume I have the following two dimensional array:

```
m_array = [['String A', 1, 1.1, 'haha'],
           ['String B', 2, 0.9, 'haha'],
           ['String C', 0, 1.1, 'haha'],
           ['String D', 3, 0.9, 'haha']]
```

**To Do:** I want to get extract the 0-index values for this multi-array, that is the 'String A', 'String B', 'String C', 'String C' and store it in a single array: `s_array` dynamically.

**Problem**: I use a for loop to iterate through all the values. Here is the code

```
    # create a single dimensional array
    s_array = []
    # Iterator is the length of the m_array. (Which should be 4; 0-index, 1-index, 2-index and 3-index     
    iterator = range(len(m_array))

    i_array = 0

    if(i_array <=iterator):
        for str_value in m_array[i_array][0]:
            s_array.append(str_value)
```

At this point s_array should be have:

`s_array['String A', 'String B', 'String C', 'String D']`

But it does NOT.

I think something is wrong with the logic of my code. But I can't identify the issue, any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect `if(i_array <=iterator):` to do?

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
s_array = [sublist[0] for sublist in m_array]
print s_array
>>> ['String A', 'String B', 'String C', 'String D']
```

Answer (score 2):

A very compact way to do this is to use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function. Given

```
m_array = [['String A', 1, 1.1, 'haha'],
           ['String B', 2, 0.9, 'haha'],
           ['String C', 0, 1.1, 'haha'],
           ['String D', 3, 0.9, 'haha']]
```

then

```
zip(*m_array)
```

returns

```
[('String A', 'String B', 'String C', 'String D'), (1, 2, 0, 3), (1.1000000000000001, 0.90000000000000002, 1.1000000000000001, 0.90000000000000002), ('haha', 'haha', 'haha', 'haha')]
```

That's because the `*` "splat" operator unpacks the items in `m_array` and passes each one as an argument to `zip`. See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the official Python tutorial.

So we just need to extract the first tuple and convert it to a list.

```
s_array = list(zip(*m_array)[0])
print(s_array)
```

**output**

```
['String A', 'String B', 'String C', 'String D']
```

Comment: base Python, this is the best approach!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel .. Why do u say it's the best approach?...What about list comprehension one?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: Thanks! I guess it wastes a little more RAM than BAH's list comp; OTOH, it's (probably) faster, especially if the sublists are long, since `zip`'s  looping happens at C speed, rather than the Python speed of a list comp `for` loop.

Comment: @Iron Fist, for speed reason and conciseness. For reading purposes it's however harder than list comprehension for non initiated.

Comment: @PM2Ring .. Yea..That was my concern in terms of what is faster, how did u determine that `zip` happens at C speed rather than Python Speed of a list comp?...Personally it would never cross my mind, since if I think of it in terms of Complexity, I feel your `zip` method seems to have more complexity than a list comp. ...Correct me if I'm wrong..:P

Comment: @IronFist: Well, `zip` _is_ written in C... at least, it is in standard Python (aka CPython). Here's the relevant [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/57c157be847f/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2490), if you're interested.

Comment: @IronFist: OTOH, to see what the speed differences are one should do some proper [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) tests. But I don't have the time to do that right now...

Comment: @PM2Ring .. appreciate the time to respond to my comments...Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through each item in `m_array[i_array][0]` and appending each item instead of appending the whole list.  You don't need to use indexing, though, because you can just iterate through `m_array`:

```
s_array = []
for array in m_array:
    s_array.append(array[0])
```

When all a `for` loop does is add things to a list, that is a sign that you can probably use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
s_array = [array[0] for array in m_array]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there's many ways. Best of all for current situation, I think, is [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36264343/1113207).

One more interesting way is to use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
m_array = [['String A', 1, 1.1, 'haha'],
           ['String B', 2, 0.9, 'haha'],
           ['String C', 0, 1.1, 'haha'],
           ['String D', 3, 0.9, 'haha']]

from operator import itemgetter

print(list(map(itemgetter(0), m_array)))
```

Comment: FWIW, I suspect that the OP is using Python 2 (otherwise they'd get an error when comparing an `int` to a `range` object). And in Python 2 the `list` call can be omitted, since  Python 2's `map` returns a `list` rather than an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I think see the issue. You are iterating through "String A" instead of m_array. m_array[i_array][0] is "String A" and you aren't changing value of i_array.

Simple fix:

```
for sublist in m_array:
    s_array.append(sublist[0])
```

I am sorry if this doesn't help but I can't ask for clarification on what are you trying to achieve (not enough reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments on [PM 2RING](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring)'s answer, I did some profiling tests which revealed the following results:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('[x[0] for x in m_array]', "m_array = [['String A', 1, 1.1, 'haha'], ['String B', 2, 0.9, 'haha'],['String C', 0, 1.1, 'haha'],['String D', 3, 0.9, 'haha']]",number = 10**6)
0.3232365940002637
>>> timeit.timeit('list(zip(*m_array))[0]', "m_array = [['String A', 1, 1.1, 'haha'], ['String B', 2, 0.9, 'haha'],['String C', 0, 1.1, 'haha'],['String D', 3, 0.9, 'haha']]",number = 10**6)
0.6186811590014258
```

Note:
Test performed on my ubuntu 14.04 Box, LENOVO THINKPAD ULTRABOOK, with CORE i7.